# GWT RPC - Enum or boolean

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

Hey, I need to send an object over an RPC, and I need to include an enum with 2 types or a boolean. The enum is far more readable, and understandable, but the boolean might send less data. I'd like to go for efficiency.

Also, I'm a bit unfamiliar with all that is passed over an RPC call. If I were to use the enum, Would it be detrimental to include the declaration of the enum inside the actual class that is transferring the object, or should I put that in a separate file?

Comment: This is a micro-optimization, I seriously doubt you'll notice one way or the other. Use an enum if it's more descriptive or if you ever expect to need a third option.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the efficiency of the request. The http header if much larger than the gwt request even if you send a few enum's. This is a (slightly anonymized) rpc call in our project (the enum is bold):

7|0|6|http://localhost:8080/project/webapp/|71407A43DECFAED2BC6095696471246F|com.ourCompanyName.common.service.FooClassObjectService|getNewElementFromParent|**com.ourCompanyName.common.types.ElementTypeEnum/1588786841**|J|1|2|3|4|2|5|6|5|2|BjH3|

As you can see, it's a very small part of the request anyway. The url/path for the rpc is a lot bigger.

I'd recommend defining the enum in a separate class. Depending on how your project is set up, the enums used for parameters must be defined in a part of the code accessible both to the frontend and the backend. (We have a project called common that defines the rpc's, the enums used, the datamodel used for transfer, and a different project for all gwt code that use the common project, but not the database project and the service project etc. that are java only.)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the answer. I'm assuming that all that is being transferred here is the enum? Wouldn't a boolean be far smaller though?

Comment: Yes, of course it would probably be only one character. But compared to the several hundreds of characters of http request header (about 700 characters in the sample request) the extra 40-50 chars required for a enum (or any other object) is negligible. As the other commenters said, this is a micro optimization. You should worry about reducing the number of requests rather than minimizing each requests size. :)